# Traverse DOM leaves in order

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking for the most efficient way of traversing the leaves of a particular element. For example:

```
<div id='root'>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div>
      <b>
        <i>Text</i>
      </b>
      <u>Underline</u>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I should get an array: `[<li>One</li>, <li>Two</li>, <p>Paragraph</p>, <i>Text</i>, <u>Underline</u>]`. Ideally it would be in this order.

Comment: An obvious is just recursively traverse and build the array when you encounter a node with no children using the childNodes property but wondering if there was a better way

Comment: @jhchen `.childNodes` gives comment nodes, text nodes etc.. you want  [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain "old" Javascript

```
(function() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#root *"),
        result;

    result = [].slice.apply(nodes).filter(function(i) {
        return i.childNodes.length === 1 && i.firstChild.nodeType === 3;
    })

    console.log(result);
}())​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/MPdrZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Not that elegant, but I think this should work (if jQuery is allowed):

```
$('#root *').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0;
});
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/9nFQ8/1/

Comment: If jQuery is "allowed" to be used :)

Comment: I would prefer it if we didn't have to use jQuery but this is a very simple and correct answer to my question